# NodeJS Mongoose with Transactions | Can't find Schemafunction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions, undefined-function

I have here the following non-working minimalexample where i want to call `customer.hello()` but I will get an `TypeError: customer.hello is not a function`.

```js
//app.js
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Customer = require('./models/Customer');

const start = async () => {
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  const session = await db.startSession();
  try {
    session.startTransaction();
    const customer = await Customer.create([{ firstName: "john" }], { session: session });
    customer.hello(); //TypeError: customer.hello is not a function
    await session.commitTransaction();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await session.abortTransaction();
  }
  finally {
    session.endSession();
  }
};

start();
```

The `customer` object after the `await customer.create`:

```
[
  {
    firstName: 'john',
    _id: new ObjectId("618fa6b968e8419bbf7ee952"),
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

```js
//Customer.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ firstName: { type: String } });

CustomerSchema.methods.hello = function () {
    console.log('helloprint');
    return "hello";
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Customer', CustomerSchema);
```

Why is `customer.hello` not a function?
If i change the code and use mongoose without transactions, I can then call the `customer.hello()` method successfully.

Comment: Try inspecting `customer` after the await.  Shouldn't it contain an array since you passed an array to `create`?

Comment: Hi Joe, I just updated my post and you can now see the content of the customer obj. It contains an array as you can see.  Thank you for the answer!!! Of course i cannot access the function because its an array. I have to write: `customer[0].hello()` to execute. Thanks for the hint and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Change `customer.hello()` to
`customer[0].hello()`